# sql query for calculate age from Birth and date field

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql table there is two fields for date of birth and date of death, how can i calculate age by using an sql query?

For example this my table:

```
id |  DOB        |  DOD  
-------------------------------
1  | 02-02-1968  |  07-21-2000
-------------------------------
2  | 08-01-1978  |  14-01-1988
```

How can i calculate age ?

Please anyone help me!!!

Comment: You have to accept some answer if you hope that someone keeps on answering you.

Comment: Moreover I hope that you've used date type to store dob and dod and not string. If this is the case consider to use str_to_date() function in order to change your format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(DOD, DOB ) as TOTAL_AGE FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select year(dod)-year(dob)-(right(dod,5)< right(dob,5) ) as age from table
```